# How to access a specific Component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I wrote a little QML application which will create an Object of a `Component` every time a button is clicked.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    property int idNumberCounter: 1

    Component {
        id: testComponent

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangleMade
            property int idNumber: 0
            width: 100
            height: 100
            x: 100*idNumber
            border.color: "blue"
        }
    }

    //The button for creating
    Rectangle {
        id: buttonMakeRectangle
        color: "red"
        width: 50
        height: 50
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                testComponent.createObject(mainWindow,idNumber:mainWindow.idNumberCounter);
                mainWindow.idNumberCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do now is to have a second button, which will e.g. change the x-Value of the rectangle with the `idNumber = 3` (if available).

Is there a way to access a specific component?

FYI: Adding a `MouseArea` to the "rectagleMade" and simply perfom the work there is not possible, because in the real application this rectangles are controlled via dBus from another application. (it will be a windowing manager with QtWayland)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could use a js array

```
Window {
    property var myList: []
    function createItem() {
        var item = testComponent.createObject(mainWindow, idNumber:mainWindow.idNumberCounter);
        myList.push(item);
        mainWindow.idNumberCounter++;
     }

     function doSomehting() {
        var item  = myList[3];
        // do something...
     }
}
```